# Split string into array but still keep it's comma when applying join. - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split

I'm having a hard time remembering how to split a string while still keeping the comma in the string and splitting special cases as well.

Example of what I'm trying to do is this:

```
> Input: "Welcome, <p>how<b>are you</p>do-ing</b>?"
> Output: ["Welcome,", " ", "<p>", "how", "<b>", "are you", "</b>", "</p>", "do-ing", "</b>", "?"]
```

What I have tried:

```
var str = "Welcome, <p>how<b>are you</p>doing</b>?",
    arr = str.split(/([,\s])/);
```

Unfortunately the only way I can think about splitting the special cases is replace them with comma's before and after them, but all this does is cause problems trying to keep the original comma. I've been scratching my head at this and I know it's right in front of me. I have tried looking all over for examples or answers and I'm drawing a blank in what I'm trying to look for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.match` instead of `.split`:

```js
var str = "Welcome, <p>how<b>are you</p>doing</b>?",
    arr = str.match(/<[^>]+>|[^,<]+,?/g);
console.log(arr);
```

The pattern `<[^>]+>|[^,<]+,?` means:

Alternate between

- `<[^>]+>` - Match `<` followed eventually by a `>`, or
- `[^,<]+,?` - Match characters other than `,` and `<`, optionally followed by a `,`

Comment: WHOA! I actually didn't know this! Thank you so much!

Comment: again thank you for this, this makes perfect sense. I had no idea something like this even existed -_-

Comment: Yep, `match` is a lot more flexible than `split`. While you *can* use `split` in quite a few limited situations, `.match` is probably the method to go to otherwise, if you can't immediately see a `split` solution working. For anything that's not extremely trivial, it's often easier to match the sequences of characters you want to match, than to match the *positions* you want to split on.